# Guideline for memoized selectors in state base class

Tags: ngxs

I have a question regarding NGXS Store and the usage of memoized `@Selector()`s in a state class hierarchy.

What would be the recommended approach to the issue described below?
The NGXS Store documentation does not provide a guideline/recommendation in this regard.

Given this sample state setup,

---

```typescript
export interface BaseModel { data: string[]; }

// base class not a state!
export class BaseState {
  @Selector()
  static dataSelect(state: BaseModel) { return state.data; }

  // ...
}
```

---

```typescript
export interface DerivedModel extends BaseModel {}

@State<DerivedModel>({ name: 'derived'; })
export class DerivedState extends BaseState {
  // ...
}
```

---

```typescript
export interface UsingModel { thing: number; }

@State<UsingModel>({ name: 'using'; })
export class UsingState implements NgxsOnInit {

  constructor(private _store: Store) {}

  ngxsOnInit(ctx: StateContext<UsingModel>) {
    // have this state update when derived state changes
    this._store.select(DerivedState.dataSelect).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }

  // ...
}
```

---

When letting this piece of code run it will print out `undefined` because the `state` argument
of the `dataSelect(...)` method will not be set.

I tracked the cause to `BaseState` not being a NGXS State and therefore missing an internal `NGXS_META`
property which in turn causes the `undefined` argument.
Adding `BaseState` to the selector (such as `@Selector([BaseState])`) to force the state to still be
included also does not have the desired effect, because now NGXS cannot navigate to a matching state slice.

I found two ways to make this work as desired:
1. duplicate the `@Selector(...)` method in every derived state implementation. This though defeats the reasons why the state class hierarchy was originally designed.
2. use something like `@DerivedSelector(...)` that works according to the standard decorator but dynamically creates selectors on use for each of the encountered derived state classes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this can not be achived using the `@Selector` annotation, but with `createSelector()`.

```
export class BaseState {
  static dataSelect() {
    return createSelector(
      [this],
      (state: BaseModel) => {
        return state.data;
      }
    );
  }

  //...
}
```

If you change your base state like this, your code will work. For details refer to the [NGXS docs](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select#inheriting-selectors)